# show that ordinal multiplication is associative

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Prove that ordinal multiplication $\alpha \cdot (\beta \cdot \gamma) = (\alpha \cdot \beta) \cdot \gamma$ is associative by using the following facts:

$$\beta \cdot 0=0$$
$$\beta \cdot (\alpha +1)=\beta \cdot \alpha+\beta$$
$$\beta \cdot \alpha=\sup\{ \beta \cdot \gamma \mid \gamma < \alpha \}$$

The second fact is for all $\alpha$ while the third fact is for all limit $\alpha \neq 0$.

I use transfinite induction to prove it. I manage to prove the base case. I stuck at successor case.

My attempt: LHS$\,=\alpha\cdot (\beta \cdot (\gamma+1))=\alpha(\beta \cdot \gamma+\beta)$

RHS$\,=(\alpha\cdot \beta)\cdot(\gamma+1)=(\alpha\cdot \beta) \cdot \gamma + (\alpha\cdot \beta)=\alpha \cdot (\beta \cdot \gamma)+(\alpha\cdot \beta)$

I don't know the distributive law, so I cannot equate LHS to RHS. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you should prove the distributive law $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$ **before** you prove the associative law?

Comment: But the distributive law comes after this question.

Comment: Is there a penalty for doing them out of order?

Comment: No, but I think the question can be proven without distributive law since the author arranges them in this way.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbecak and Jech.

Comment: I don't have that book. How do they define ordinal multiplication? is $\alpha\beta$ defined as the ordinal type of the Cartesian product $\alpha\times\beta$ ordered lexicographically by last differences? Or something like that? Maybe you should try to prove associativity directly from the definition, instead of trying to use transfinite induction?

Comment: There are three ordinals here. What exactly is your transfinite induction hypothesis?

Comment: I use transfinite induction on $\gamma$.

Comment: I assume you have ordinal product defined by recursion (in the big Jech's it's done that way). Then there seems to be no way to do this without proving the distributive law first, and for that you should prove before (at least) that $+$ is monotone.